# Google Scripts pulling certain data from one tab to another (where column is TRUE)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from one spreadsheet tab to another but only when column 37 is true!  I tried adding a looping script but it is not working

Basically, the sort tab is sorting viable data from the output sheet and column 37 lets me know if it's viable or not by putting a True in that column.  I need to use google scripts for its time triggers or else I would use a query.

```
function sortData() {

var sourceSpreadsheetID = "1qweQjoTmmXYxc3-6jyB6XhZrfpfl1s7UpP1SnzzAOuA";
var sourceWorksheetName = "Output";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "1qweQjoTmmXYxc3-6jyB6XhZrfpfl1s7UpP1SnzzAOuA";
var targetWorksheetName = "Sort";
var holdingData = [];

  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var k = 1; k <= thisData.length; k++) {
     if (thisWorksheet.getRange(k,37).getValue() == 'TRUE') {    
       holdingData.push(thisData[k])
     }
   }
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  toWorksheet.clearContents();
  toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, holdingData.length, holdingData[0].length).setValues(holdingData); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to filter the data array

```
  holdingData =  thisData .filter(function(dataRow) { return dataRow[37] === true})
```

instead of this loop

```
  for (var k = 1; k <= thisData.length; k++) {
     if (thisWorksheet.getRange(k,37).getValue() == 'TRUE') {    
       holdingData.push(thisData[k])
     }
   }
```

Comment: I get a filter undefined error!  I am very abysmal with google scripts

Comment: Try it this way  `holdingData =  thisData .filter(function(dataRow) { return dataRow[37] === true})`

Comment: Ok that worked but no data came over? do i still keep the for function or no?

Comment: Change 37 to 36 - because the 37th column of the sheet is the 36th element of the array
I ran your code and got a selection result

Comment: remove the for loop from code. Instead of a for loop , write this `holdingData =  thisData .filter(function(dataRow) { return dataRow[36] === true})`

Comment: Its running but still pulling the FALSE data

Comment: it's strange, because when I run this script - I only get lines that have TRUE in the AK column. I recorded a video in which I first read all the data from your source and then read only the filtered data by condition Column AK = TRUE [link to video](https://www.hippovideo.io/video/play/502gQXagN4HGelaYPICCppUOlUY3sqajeb3B5PlyC5Y)